# What constitutes AGILITY where Behavior-Driven and Unit Testing are concerned

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, tdd, bdd

This morning I had a presentation on [PHPSPec](https://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/) which the official website describes as follows:

> A php toolset to drive emergent design by specification.

As defined within an adjective context the word "emergent" is defined as follow:

> the process of coming into being

On the other hand [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) is said to focus on quick code commits and asserting that no code regression occurs in other parts of the code.

With that being said the argument that came out of presentation is that PHPSpec is still a unit test framework which I did, in no way disputed that, but mine I think was more on what the tool really focuses on which is design.

The differences among these two tools is succinctly explained in this [article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/whats-the-difference-between-phpunit-and-phpspec) on Laracasts.

Now comes Agile Methodology  which is explained [here](https://blog.azendoo.com/agile-project-management-methodology-explained/) and [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3237508/agile-development/what-is-agile-methodology-modern-software-development-explained.html). The latter article on Agile Methodology highlights mentions why this methodology is better (***see below for an excerpt***).

> When you take the aggregate of agile principles, implement them in an
>   agile framework, leverage collaboration tools, and adopt agile
>   development practices, you usually get better-quality applications,
>   faster-developed applications, and better technical practices (aka
>   hygiene).

The view is that PHPSpec offers nothing that PHPUnit does not. However, if we look into the Engineering discipline and what it is about we can almost see the mention of tools ([see below excerpt](https://www.unr.edu/cse/prospective-students/what-is-software-engineering)):

> It encompasses concepts, principles, theories, techniques and **tools**
>   that can be used for developing high-quality professional software.

Looking at all this within the perspective of Continuous Integration tools include, in that context, things like PHPSpec, PHPUnit, Behat, Codeception and so forth for achieving varying test strategies. Within an engineering context all these tools have roles to play. However, it does seem that one cannot use the other, particularly PHPSPec, within an Agile environment. What I think lacks is a real-world context where one can really drive Test-Driven and Behavior-Driven Design using these two tools in particular.

I might be wrong in how I have been seeing things within the context of Agility coupled with Software Engineering strategies to deliver high quality code and so forth. I do not claim to be Mr Know-it-all mine is to try and become better and knowledgeable within my profession and thus improve on my skills.

Can somebody please help me understand Agile Methodology when mixed with Software Engineering within the context of PHP and how one can go about implementing a Software Product Development process taking advantage of readily available testing tools and strategies out there? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no “Agile Methodology”, only [The Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/). It is just a set of values and principles to guide our decisions.

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks for the response... And from your view I can safely say how one shapes his process really dependent on them entirely as long as they are guided by the Manifesto itself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Behavior-Driven and Unit Testing are some technical aspects supporting the feasibility/success of the whole development process driven by agile practices.

Agility comes from taking less iterations/time to achieve delivering a product that meets the actual (real value adding) user's requirements effectively [[1](https://www.frontrowagile.com/blog/posts/91-3-reasons-you-need-to-seek-feedback-in-your-agile-process)], because of these reasons:

- The agile principles/framework you mentioned, essentially drives to replace the waterfall paradigm that looks for define ALL requirements at a first analysis phase with documentation only, by delivering to the users a working application (not complete) really fast, getting feedback quickly and planning the next short iteration/sprint with users feedback over a real working app.
  This is because the empirical observation that in most of cases, users discover their real and most priority needs using and interacting with a working application (even if is incomplete), and this is a better method than a long analysis phase only with documentation. [[2](http://kartowicz.com/dryobates/2015-03/requirements_change_and_tdd/)] 
  This way the process is more agile, since is driven by small iterations/sprints with constant user's feedback, resulting in a faster achievement of a product meeting real needs and giving more value added. [[3](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/agile-vs-waterfall/)]
- In order to support this uncertainty of future changes coming, and also the need of implement them in fast small steps (iterations/sprints), without risks, the source code needs to have a really good architecture/design, flexible and ready for change without being buggy or fragile. [[4](http://mhjongerius.tumblr.com/post/61853273412/the-seven-design-smells-of-rotting-software)]
  Here is where Behavior-Driven, TDD, Unit Testing, ... (XP practices) comes as technical practices to help producing more robust source code, ready for change in a safe way.
  Requirements are written as source code examples (unit/integration/acceptance/e2e tests) instead of just word documents that usually becomes obsolete. CI (Continuous Integration) ensures these requirements written as source code are validated on every developer's check-in. [[5](https://blog.red-badger.com/blog/2012/07/31/what-is-specification-by-example)]  
  The 3 TDD steps (Cycles of TDD: Red-Green-Refactor) ensures there is no more source code than needed for the current iteration that is known gives value to the users, avoiding to deal with over designed code. 
  Also these 3 steps makes developers focuses in different development aspects once at time: defining requirements when writing them as automated tests, creating algorithms when implementing the source code for the current test, and designing and architecture on refactoring step. [[6](https://softwareasscience.blogspot.com/2014/02/tdd-test-driven-development-in-practice.html)] 
  Separating these 3 aspects of software development on different times, decreases bugs risks that happens when developers realizes not considered scenarios  while implementing algorithms and they have to start to make the 3 aspects at the same time. [[7](http://emilybache.blogspot.com/2011/05/tdd-in-terms-of-states-and-moves.html)] 
  Unit tests ensures the source code must complains with SR (Single Responsibility) and DI (Dependency Inversion) principles (of all five SOLID principles), the other good practices and design patters are applied on refactor phase, but since source code complies with SR, DI and requirements are automated tested with CI, the team can refactor with more confidence and is not driven by the fear of unexpected side effects.
- All of these practices, if they are well implemented, ends with a high quality code, robust and ready for change. Allowing the team to iterate faster over the user's feedback, and also over the unexpected market changes that even the users are unable to control or predict.
- This is from Agility comes, compared with waterfall paradigm (when is used for scenarios requiring much innovation or uncertainly about future requirements), where the strategy for be ready for change is commonly to over design trying to predict possible evolution, that can make the software too complex and harder to evolve when the real market/user required changes comes, specially not having good coverage with automated tests, changes generates unexpected side effects and projects become delayed by many bugs and a long QA stabilizing phase, this produces fear of change and sometimes ends with implementing changes with not optimal patches/workarounds instead of necessary refactors producing a worst fragile/brittle source code, harder to maintain and evolve. [[8](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/15279)]